# Most efficient way to create form with multiple nested relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im working on a RPG character sheet (specifically DnD first, but will be universal) and while I got some advice on how to structure my database and Ive got that setup and I understand how its going to work.  Im having trouble figuring out the best way to set up the character edit form.

My Database is structured the following for character attributes

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :character_sheets, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :character_attributes, through: :character_sheets
end

class CharacterAttribute < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :character_sheets
    has_many :characters, through: :character_sheets
end

class CharacterSheet < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :character
    belongs_to :character_attribute
end
```

The database schema looks like this:

```
    create_table "character_attributes", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.index ["game_type_id"], name: "index_character_attributes_on_game_type_id"
      end

create_table "character_sheets", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer "character_id"
        t.integer "character_attribute_id"
        t.integer "value_int"
        t.text "value_char"
        t.boolean "value_boolean"
        t.index ["character_attribute_id"], name: "index_character_sheets_on_character_attribute_id"
        t.index ["character_id"], name: "index_character_sheets_on_character_id"
      end

create_table "characters", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.integer "user_id"
        t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_characters_on_user_id"
      end
```

This all works and stores the info but its a lot of extra queries to display every attribute (upwards of 100) and each attribute ends up doing 2 queries per attribute i display which would get excessive very quickly.  Just for reference this is how I did my quick test to display the info:

```
<% @level = @character.character_attributes.find_by(name: 'Level')%>
<%= @level.name %>
<%= @character.character_sheets.find_by(character_attribute_id: @level.id).value_int %>
```

Is there a better way to display the information or to do an initial query to get everything so I only query the database once?  Also planning to use the best_in_place gem to allow in place editing of all the fields

Comment: I would consider if you really want to use the EAV pattern. Sure it makes it really flexible to add whatever attributes but you have to pay through the nose for that flexibility in terms of complexity and performance.

Comment: I would either use a fixed schema (a table where each attribute is a column), a JSON column or non-sql database like Mongodb.

Comment: I looked at using a noSQL option, but with Rails its kinda a pain and everything ive read said to avoid it